# Mootools Multiselect check all is very slow in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, mootools

We are facing a performance issue when we click on 'All' link in grouped multiselect drop down component when we have many values (around 100 values) in the drop down.

This is issue is occurring only in IE8 and working fine in the other browsers. After our initial analysis we observed that

The below lines in the function changeItemState of multiselect.js file is causing this problem in IE8. Can you please provide us any work around for this

```
monitor.set('html', '
 + this.changeMonitorValue(item.getParent()) + 
);
monitor.title = this.getHoverTitle(item.getParent());
```

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle os JSBin that reproduces your problem? And btw, why the quotes and concat `+` sign in `this.changeMonitorValue` ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure when you have removed the actual code but when you say you have 100 values - especially with getters - this is likely to be a problem in IE8 or less.

Strings in javascript are immutable. This means if you need to concatenate 100 strings, it will create a new one, add the next one to it and cleanup 100 times. This is not very performant in IE, hence a lot of people used to do `Array.join('')` instead:

```
var foo = 'a' + 'b' + 'c' + 'd', // faster in modern and mobile browsers
    bar = ['a','b','c','d'].join(''); // faster by ~50% IE7, IE8
```

http://jsperf.com/string-concat-vs-array-join-10000/9

However, the array join trick is slower in mobile devices, andorid and modern browsers.

Another optimisation can be that you add change handlers that export the current values into an array during form manipulation (your model), thus negating the need to get 100 ones in one go on the submit event.

Since the parents of nodes are immutable (likely), there is no need to go to `item.getParent()` either all the time, you can do that as a one off before-hand or even reference `item.parentNode` directly to avoid a function call.

post `changeMonitorValue` source for optimisations that can take place there as it's likely sub-optimal. I expect you are using http://mootools.net/forge/p/mutiselect?

If so, https://github.com/mlazz/MultiSelect/blob/master/Source/MultiSelect.js can be optimised A LOT. however, that's something for the plugin author.

Be creative :)